# $A^k$ and nonzero elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $A^k=0$ for some $k\geq 2$, at most how many nonzero elements could $A$ have if its element is either $0$ or $1$?

My attempt:
Sylvester rank inequality gives $rank(A)\leq n(k-1)/k$. Does that mean the answer is $n(k-1)/k$? If $k=2$ and $n=2$, the bound is $1$. It seems ok. But rigorously how to improve?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add that you are speaking about a field $F$ with char$(F)=0$. Otherwise, you can take a $2\times 2$ matrix over $F_2$ with all elements are 1. Then $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed bound is not true. Let $n=2m$ and $$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} 0 &j\le m\\
0 & j>m,\ i>m\\
1 & j>m,\ i\le m
\end{cases}$$
Then $A^2=0.$ The matrix $A$ has $m^2=n^2/4$ positive entries.

For $n=2m+1$ let
$$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} 0 &j\le m\\
0 & j> m,\ i>m\\
1 & j\ge m,\ i\le m
\end{cases}$$
Then $A^2=0$ and the matrix $A$ has $(m+1)m=(n^2-1)/4$ positive entries.